# How to work with dynamically loaded elements in YUI

Tags: yui

I'm currently trying to integrate spring mvc app using YUI3. I was able to call Spring Controller with static href in jsp through YUI, but script is not getting invoked when trying to invoke dynamically generated href.

```
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.14.1/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
                        <script>
                        YUI().use('io-form', 'json','datatable','node','tabview',function(Y) {
                        Y.all('#nav a').on('click', function (ev) {
                                ev.preventDefault();
                                //main.load(ev.target.get('href'), '#content');
                                var href = ev.target.get('href');
                                var url = href.substring(0,href.indexOf('#'));
                                var idw = href.substring(href.indexOf('#')+1,href.length);
                                Y.io(url, {
                                    method: 'GET',
                                    on: {
                                    complete: function(id, response) {
                                    answer = Y.JSON.parse(response.responseText);
                                    Y.log(answer);
                                    var main = Y.one('#'+idw); 
                                    var node = main.all('li');

                                    if(node.size()===0){
                                    Y.Object.each(answer, function(item, index){

                                            main.append("<li id='"+item+"' class='api-list-item class'><a href='/YUI-2-Spring/getContactDetails/"+item+".html#"+item+"'>"+item+"</a></li>");


                                    });
                                    }
                                    }

                                    }
                                    });

                                });
                        //To call controller on clickin of dynamic links
                                Y.all('#api-Types a').on('click', function (ev) {
                                ev.preventDefault();
                                //main.load(ev.target.get('href'), '#content');
                                var href = ev.target.get('href');

                                var neturl = href.substring(0,href.indexOf('#'));
                                var studId= href.substring(href.indexOf('#')+1,href.length); 
                                Y.io(neturl, {
                                    method: 'GET',
                                    on: {
                                    complete: function(id, response) {
                                    answer = Y.JSON.parse(response.responseText);
                                    Y.log(answer);
                                    var main = Y.one('#api-everything'); 
                                    var node = main.all('li');
                                    if(node.size()===0){
                                    Y.Object.each(answer, function(item, index){

                                            main.append("<li id='"+item+"' class='module-class'><a href='/YUI-2-Spring/getPersonalDetails/"+item+"/"+contId+"'</a>"+item+"</li>");


                                    });
                                    }
                                    }

                                    }
                                    });

                                });
                        });
                        </script>
```

The first script I'm using for calling controller on tabview selection .Based on that I'm creating a list of String with href inside `<ul id="api-Types" class="apis modules"></ul>` field. In the next script, I'm trying to invoke the generated links, but script is not getting executed.

```
<div class="yui3-u-1-4">
                        <div id="docs-sidebar" class="sidebar apidocs">
                            <div id="api-list">
                        <h2 class="off-left">APIs</h2>
                        <div id="api-tabview" class="yui3-tabview-content">
                            <ul id="nav" class="tabs">
                                <li class="yui3-tab yui3-widget yui3-tab-selected"><a href="/YUI-2-Spring/getAllElements.html#api-elements">Elements</a></li>
                                <li class="yui3-tab yui3-widget"><a href="/YUI-2-Spring/getContactDetails.html#api-Types">Contact Details</a></li>
                                <li class="yui3-tab yui3-widget"><a href="#api-everything">All</a></li>
                            </ul>



                            <div id="yui3-tabview-panel">

                                 <ul id="api-elements" class="apis classes">
                                 <input type="search" id="api-filter" placeholder="Type to filter APIs">
                                 </ul>
                                  <ul id="api-Types" class="apis modules">
                                  <input type="search" id="api-filter" placeholder="Type to filter APIs"></ul>

                                     <ul id="api-everything" class="apis search">
                                     <input type="search" id="api-filter" placeholder="Type to filter APIs">
                                        <li class="message">
                                            Begin typing in the search box above to see results.
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

This is the dynamic list that got generated got from viewsource:

```
 <ul id="api-Types" class="apis modules yui3-tab-panel yui3-tab-panel-selected" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="yui_3_14_1_1_1389513296688_62">
                      <input type="search" id="api-filter" placeholder="Type to filter APIs"><li  class="api-list-item class"><a href="/YUI-2-Spring/getContactDetails/ABC.html#ABC" id="yui_3_14_1_1_1389513296688_227">ABC</a></li><li id="BCD" class="api-list-item class"><a href="/YUI-2-Spring/getContactDetails/BCD.html#BCD">BCD</a></li><li id="CDE" class="api-list-item class"><a href="/YUI-2-Spring/getContactDetails/CDE.html#CDE">CDE</a></li><li id="DEF" class="api-list-item class"><a href="/YUI-2-Spring/getContactDetails/DEF.html#DEF">DEF</a></li><li id="EFG" class="api-list-item class"><a href="/YUI-2-Spring/getContactDetails/EFG.html#EFG">EFG</a></li><li id="FGH" class="api-list-item class"><a href="/YUI-2-Spring/getContactDetails/FGH.html#FGH">FGH</a></li></ul>
```

When I'm clicking on the links, instead of invoking the script, my controller is getting invoked through Dispatcher servlet.
        Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To bind events on dynamically added element on DOM you should use 'delegate' to bind event instead of 'on'. It will work.